# The Arguments in a python class

Tags: python

In a class I need to fully understand(know) the arguments and the given while coding in Python,please use the below as an example or any other more complicated.

```
class Beacon(object):

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.paths = {}

    def go(self, direction):
        return self.paths.get(direction)

    def add_paths(self, paths): 
        self.paths.update(paths)
```

I may try to cause an error by removing description from

```
def __init__(self, name):
```

and run a test,What i get is TypeError: init() takes exactly 2 arguments(3 given), please I want to know which ones are the arguments and the given ones here.

Comment: Hint: `self` is passed _implicitly_.

Comment: name and description are the arguments. `self` is self refrence of the class  instance - similar to `this` in other programming languages.

Comment: Does it mean self is also an argument?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments that you need to instantiate class `Beacon` are `name` and `description`. The argument `self` gets the object that you are instantiating "under the hood". (you don't have to do it yourself, python does it for you)

For example:

```
class Person:
     def __init__(self, name, age):
         self.name = name
         self.age = age
```

To instantiate the `Person` class:

`jack = Person("Jack", 33)`

We passed `"Jack"` string as `name` and integer `33` as `age`. 
As you can see we don't pass any arguments as `self`. 
`self` actually takes `jack` (the name of the variable) as an argument, but it gets done automatically, so you don't have to worry about it. `__init__` method takes 3 arguments only 2 of which you have to pass yourself.

Comment: When you want to have block of code, indent each line (excluding empty lines) using 4 spaces.

Comment: That means jack as the variable is 1 argument replacing self.

Comment: Now, How is __init__ function related to go and add_paths functions?

Comment: `__init__` is not _related_ to `add_paths` function. `__init__` declares empty dictionary (`{}`) without any elements, and with `add_paths` function you can update `self.paths` dictionary by passing key/value pair  as `paths` to `add_paths` function call.

Comment: what of the go function,how is it related to add_paths or are they working differently?  Be plain with me i want to get something right here.

Comment: they are all working differently. `go` function just returns value of the given key `direction`, whereas `add_paths` adds new paths to the `self.paths` dictionary. they all work independantly.

Answer (score 0):

Self is mandatory argument (instance to the class), but it's passed. First argument is "name", second "description" etc.

Answer (score -1):

The arguments for **init** function in your code are: 
 - self
 - name
 - description

When you remove the description argument the error appears because the **init** function is trying to create the attribute self.description from the argument description.

Comment: The error is actually as a result of the OP trying to create an instance and passing the wrong number of arguments.  The text of the error would be different if the if it was the init method making use of a argument that doesn't exist.